# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, illegalargumentexception, virtualfilesystem

I am trying to deploy a WAR to JBoss, but it throws below exception:

```
13:47:05,031 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test.ear"."TestWeb.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Test.ear"."TestWeb.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "TestWeb.war" of deployment "Test.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:116) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:110) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.processTlds(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.deploy(TldParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete Previous deployment from jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standlone/deployments.